# Getting Row Count and Echo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table with a total of 10 rows and 5 of those rows have the status set to number 1 and the others set to 0. What i'm trying to achieve is the simplest method of displaying the total count of the rows that have their status set to the number 1.

```
<?php echo (empty( $this->fetchData[2][0]['pickup_status'] ) ? 'No New Pickups' : $this->fetchData[2][0]['pickup_status'] ); ?>
```

The above code should show "5" instead of "No New Pickups", how can i make this work? I still want "No New Pickups" to be shown if the status is not number 1.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class='dashicon'>

            <a href='<?php echo _URL_PATH; ?>packages/pickups'>
            <span class="notify-badge">PHP ECHO</span>
                <img src='<?php echo _URL_PATH . IMGS_PATH; ?>bicon_pickups.png' />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class='dashname'>
            Pickup Requests
        </div>

        <div class='dashdesc'>
            Manage package pickup request details
        </div>

    </div>

<?php

$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sysPickupRequest WHERE pickup_status = 1");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];

?>
```

Comment: I am trying to display a overall count in a css badge that shows how many rows have their status set to number 1 by grabbing the total count from SQL.

Comment: `The above code should show "5" instead of "No New Pickups",` PHP does not lie or does not have misinterpretation `empty( $this->fetchData[2][0]['pickup_status'] )` is `true` no question about that.. Now you need to figure out why `$this->fetchData[2][0]['pickup_status']` is empty.. Why can't help you without knowing the data and PHP code.

Comment: read the above comment this would explain @RaymondNijland

Comment: We could help you better if you showed us the query you use to get your data from the dbms. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: This problem does not appear to be reproducible with the code shown here.

Comment: the query that is being used is being executed by a controller file and a model file, thats why im looking for the most easiest solution. @O.Jones

Answer (score 2):

Your query does not do what you want.

```
 SELECT * FROM sysPickupRequest WHERE pickup_status = 1;
```

This returns the details in potentially many rows, and potentially no rows. What it *doesn't* return is a count of anything.  You want something like this instead. It returns one row and one column, the count you need.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) status1 FROM sysPickupRequest WHERE pickup_status = 1;
```

Or if you want both the total number of rows and the number with status 1, you can do this:

```
 SELECT SUM(pickup_status = 1) AS status1, COUNT(*) AS total FROM sysPickupRequest;
```

It works because the expression `pickup_status = 1` has the value 1 when it's true and the value 0 when it's false. You `SUM()` up a bunch of ones and zeros.

So it works like this in your case. (I haven't debugged this code.)

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(pickup_status = 1) AS status1, COUNT(*) AS total FROM sysPickupRequest;"
$status1 = 0;
if ($resultSet=mysqli->query($query)) {
     if ($row=$resultSet->fetch_assoc($resultSet)) {
         $status1 = $row['status1'];
     } else die 'fetch error';
} else die 'query error';
$pickupStatus = $status1 != 0 ? $status1 :  'No New Pickups';
echo $pickupStatus;
```

Comment: Would this require a new database connection with the code in order for it to function?

Comment: I would use SUM and fetch just one column.  But I like it!

Comment: Yeah i only need it to fetch one column